# Django always acesses default DB

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an API with a dynamic database (based on the client accessing it), but for testing purposes, I manually defined two in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'test1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'model_base1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
    },
    'test2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'model_base2',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
    },
}
```

I have this view file:

```
from rest_framework import generics

from cadastro.models.enderecos import Enderecos
from cadastro.serializers.enderecos  import EnderecosSerializer

class EnderecoListarCriarAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Enderecos.objects.using('test1').all()
    serializer_class = EnderecosSerializer
```

and I have this serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from cadastro.models.enderecos import Enderecos

class EnderecosWriteOnlyMixin:
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields['id_referencia'].read_only = True
        fields['tipo_tabela_referencia'].read_only = True
        return fields

class EnderecosSerializer(EnderecosWriteOnlyMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id_referencia = serializers.IntegerField()
    tipo_tabela_referencia = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Enderecos
        fields = [
            "id_endereco",
            "id_referencia",
            "tipo_tabela_referencia",
            "cep",
            "logradouro",
            "numero",
            "complemento",
            "bairro",
            "cidade",
            "uf",
        ]

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # Aplicar uppercase para todos os campos
        for field_name, field_value in data.items():
            if isinstance(field_value, str):
                data[field_name] = field_value.upper()
        
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Model.py of this view / serializer:

```
from django.db import models
from cadastro.validators.enderecos import *


class Enderecos(models.Model):
    id_endereco = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cep = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_cep]
    )
    numero = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_numero]
    )
    logradouro = models.CharField(
        max_length=150, blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_logradouro]
    )
    complemento = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_complemento]
    )
    bairro = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_bairro]
    )
    cidade = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_cidade]
    )
    uf = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_uf]
    )
    endereco_principal = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, blank=False, null=False, default="F"
    )

    # Campos para referenciar o tipo de tabela e ID
    tipo_tabela_referencia = models.IntegerField()
    id_referencia = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "tb_endereco"
```

Why do I get this error whenever I try to post data into this table? (Django is selecting the default database even if I manually specified the database to be used):

```
queryset = Enderecos.objects.using('test1').all()
```

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /cadastro/enderecos/
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Note: If I rename "test1" to "default" in settings.py and remove the "using" in the view file, it works, but it's not intended to be this way because there is no default database.

Comment: What about your routers.py file?

Comment: I don't have a router.py, since the documentation doesn't specify that a router is needed for manual database selection. Or it is? I'm new in Django (I usually use Flask)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases) state *"Django requires that a default database entry be defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will not be used. To do this, you must set up DATABASE_ROUTERS for all of your apps’ models"*.  I believe this means that since you are defining the default as `{}` you *must* use a [router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers).

Comment: What's the traceback on that error? Is it happening during the query you describe, or during Django's checks? Can you provide the full traceback as an edit to your question?

Comment: The problem was fixed after configuring the router.py file appropriately. Thanks. I added a middleware for database selection and cache in the middleware / router / view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Django requires that a default database entry be defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will not be used. To do this, you must set up DATABASE_ROUTERS for all of your apps’ models, including those in any contrib and third-party apps you’re using, so that no queries are routed to the default database.
> [Defining your databases.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases)

Therefore you’ve got to [use routers.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)